# "Variable" cannot be resolved to type?! - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm creating a simple file browser GUI, but i'm getting these errors! Its saying the BrwoseFile and sendfile cannot be resolved to a type? But it works on uni computers. Any ideas?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
BrowseFile cannot be resolved to a type
SendFile cannot be resolved to a type
```

This is the code for my gui:

```
public class NetZipGUI implements Runnable{

private JLabel path;
private JTextField file;
private JButton send;


public void run() {
    JFrame gui = new JFrame("File Explorer");
    gui.setSize(400, 300);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container pane = gui.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel TPanel = new JPanel();
    TPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(TPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    path = new JLabel("File path");
    file = new JTextField(40);

    TPanel.add(path);
    TPanel.add(file);

    JButton browse = new JButton("Browse file");     
    TPanel.add(browse);
    browse.addActionListener(new BrowseFile());<---- Here

    pane.add(TPanel);

    JPanel BPanel = new JPanel();

    send = new JButton("Send file");
    send.setEnabled(false);
    BPanel.add(send);
    send.addActionListener(new SendFile());<---- Here

    pane.add(BPanel);

    gui.pack();
    gui.setVisible(true);

   class BrowseFile implements ActionListener{


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int value = 0; 

        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.showOpenDialog(fc);

        if(value == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File sF = fc.getSelectedFile();
            file.setText(sF.getAbsolutePath());
            send.setEnabled(true);

        }

    }

}

class SendFile implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }
}

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new NetZipGUI());
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Your curly braces are not properly matched. If you want to declare a named type inside a method, you need to do it before the first use of the type. Otherwise, you need to bring the nested class to the enclosing class level. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `BrowseFile` starts in the middle of the `run` method. You first need to close the `run` method in order to properly define an inner class like `BrowseFile`. The same with `SendFile`. Basically, just move the third-last `}` up in front of the `BrowseFile` class definition.